# Load SWF data without loading sound, then load sound later

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, load

So, hypothetical situation here:

I have an SWF that's 30MB.  Sound files (music) make up 25MB, art and other things make up the remaining 5MB.

Would it be possible for me to load the 5MB of necessary art and other things first to allow the user to operate the app, then after that's all loaded and they are operating the app, load the remaining 25MB of sound files in the background?

UPDATE:
Loading SWF (or other entities) externally is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the compilation settings and strategically placing the sound.

By default, anything placed on the timeline will be loaded sequentially; the Flash Player will play the SWF as soon as the first frame is loaded.  If you use the default compilation settings, all library content will be placed in the first frame, so the movie doesn't start until everything is available.

You can modify these settings, however, to allow for a more sequential load order:  For each of your library elements, you can uncheck "export into frame 1" in the properties window.  Now these elements won't be loaded, until they appear in the main timeline.  This way, if you place your content carefully, you can allow for all important elements to be loaded in the first frame, or if you have a progress bar, until the main movie starts, while all streaming elements load with the animation, which has to be placed accordingly.  Make sure though, that you don't leave anything out (by not placing it on the timeline), or call elements from ActionScript before they are loaded completely.  It is very important to test this thoroughly, because if anything goes wrong in the load order, your entire SWF might stop working.

Also, remember that the SWF loads sequentially: If you have a sound in, say, frame 300, and another in frame 1000, the one in 300 will be loaded first.  If you jump to frame 1000 from a menu in frame 10, you have to take into account that the frame might not be loaded yet. So there has to be some sort of checking mechanism ([framesLoaded](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#framesLoaded)) and/or dialog to inform the user about additional loading time, and prevent the application from crashing.